# Does jquery.js cache in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery.js and i want to know does the browser cache the jquery file or this file transfer for each page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Caching has nothing to do with a particular file, it's all about the headers for this file.

By default most file will be cached however the duration of the caching depends on the header setting for the file. So yes it should be cached with a default setup.

Here is a little information about caching http://www.web-caching.com/mnot_tutorial/how.html

Comment: correct answer. i would suggest to reference the file via a cdn (content delivery network) if possible. That way, you do not have to consider things like caching and if a user visits your page, he might have already cached that file before on a different page (saving yet another http request) 

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Answer (score 1):

It depends on both the server and the client. Once the client has a file, it can use the `If-Modified-Since` header to tell the server about a cached copy of a file. The server can then respond with a `304` status with optional `Last-Modified`, `Expires` and `Cache-Control` headers, to indicate the status of caching and when the client should request for a new copy. If a cached copy isn't available, the server can respond normally.

You should consider using one of the publicly hosted jQuery files: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

These are more likely to be cached on a client.